# powershell - Get-TSSession credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, credentials

When using the [Get-TSSession cmdlet](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSTerminalServices) to query a remote server in a different domain, I keep getting access denied messages:

```
get-tssession -computername localhost - WORKS FINE
get-tssession -computername 192.168.0.1 - WORKS FINE (Server in same domain)
get-tssession -computername 192.168.1.1 - GIVES ACCESS DENIED (Server in a different domain)
```

I think this is due to the different domain and therefor different admin username and password.

Does anyone know of a way around this? maybe running the cmdlet as a different user with different credentials? I don't won't the script to prompt for a password as this is an auto script that runs at night.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the TS Session cmdlets are using Kerberos for authentication (this also rings a few bells in my heads... TS team was upstairs), which means you'll need to hop in thru PowerShell remoting and use CredSSP.

You can setup CredSSP by using Enable/Disable-WSManCredSSP. Connect to the other box with domain creds for the 2nd box, and you should be good to go.

Please let me know if this works.

Hope this Helps